# Comparing Column Values Between Two Tables

Tags: php, sql

So I created a little thing here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7a76/1

And it does what I want there, but doesn't work when applied to my actual PHP. On load, the HTML page displays all cable numbers in a dropdown from what is in the 'bundle_lanes' SQL database. But recently my client now wants the cable numbers to disappear if they exist already in the database 'cabletypes'. So I need some way to tell SQL to look for exact cable number match and don't display them if they exist in both tables. What am I doing wrong? It works in the sqlfiddle. No error, just blank results when I run the cableNumbers.php and an empty drop down box.

HTML (index.php)

```
 <body onload="cable_numbers(); company_name();">
<select id="cable_no" onchange="update_section_no();" return false;>
                        <option value="">Cable Number</option>
                    </select>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//Set Cable Numbers in DropDown
function cable_numbers() {
$.ajax({
    url: './php/cableNumbers.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(mydata) {

        var combo = document.getElementById("cable_no");

            while (combo.firstChild) {
                combo.removeChild(combo.firstChild);
            };

            var option = document.createElement("option");

            for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
                option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = mydata[i]['cable_no'];
                option.value = mydata[i]['cable_no'];
                try {
                    combo.add(option, null); //Standard
                } catch (error) {
                    combo.add(option); // IE only
                }
            };
         section_numbers(); 
    }
});
};
```

PHP cableNumbers.php (where the SQL query lives)

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cable_no FROM bundle_lanes 
        WHERE (cable_no) NOT IN (SELECT cable_no FROM cabletypes)
        ORDER BY cable_no ASC";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error'.mysql_error());

// If DB query successful then send data to calling routine.
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }           
    print json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: When you say' It does not work' do you mean that the returned query is incorrect or php is displaying the incorrect results? I'd run the query on your db first then go from there.

Comment: In what way does it not work in your code? Does it not populate the combobox at all? Do you get an error?

Comment: I'm sorry, it just returns a blank dropdown with no values in it. No error, just nothing is populated in the dropdown.

Comment: Are you getting the correct data when you directly browse `/php/cableNumbers.php`?

Comment: I am getting no data at all... but when I just use "SELECT DISTINCT cable_no FROM bundle_lanes ORDER BY cable_no ASC"; I get all results from that table, but the issue is some of those cable numbers ALSO exist in the cabletype table as well and that needs to require a check between the two databases.

Comment: Are you sure the `bundle_lanes` records aren't already in the `cabletypes` table?

Comment: well i made one that only exists in bundle_lanes and made sure it's not in the other table and it's not even returning that value :( the idea is that one is a warehouse table( bundle lanes) and the other samples the warehouse cable number and then inserts that cable type in the cabletypes database, so therefore once it's been samples, it doesn't need to show up again.

Comment: Is the query in the fiddle the actual one you are using in your code? You'd probably better rewrite it this way for performance reasons, maybe give it a try: `SELECT b.cable_no 
FROM bundle_lanes AS b LEFT JOIN cabletypes AS c ON b.cable_no = c.cable_no 
WHERE c.cable_no IS NULL 
GROUP BY b.cable_no 
ORDER BY b.cable_no `

Comment: Does it work when you query the DB directly? If it does, then there is something wrong with your PHP code. If it does not, then there is something wrong with your data.

Comment: If I query it directly (using SQLWorkbench) I also get blank results, 0 rows returned. I checked my two tables, bundle_lanes has cable_no column as VARCHAR and cabletypes has that column as INT. Is that a discrepancy causing the issue? EDIT: Changed to varchar for both and data still won't show... What do you mean by a data problem?

Comment: It's gotta be a data problem. I see no reason from what you've posted that it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Eggplant DUDE! I think you just fixed it for me... HOW and WHY? It seems to be working!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. HOW: you are joining all the records in `bundle_lanes` table with those which corresponds in `cabletypes` table, filtering and keeping only the ones where there is no match in the `cabletypes` table (hence the `IS NULL`). Then `GROUP BY b.cable_no` to remove duplicate entries and order them. It is quite a standard way to improve the `WHERE field NOT IN (subquery)` construct, it takes advantage of indexes and does not execute useles subqueries multiple times. As for the WHY, well, you probably used a different query than the one in the fiddle :)  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
select distinct bundle_lanes.cable_no 
from bundle_lanes left outer join cabletypes on 
     (bundle_lanes.cable_no = cabletypes.cable_no) 
where cabletypes.cable_no is null
order by bundle_lanes.cable_no
```

Comment: That's it! Credit to Eggplant, but you answered it too :) thanks... why does it work that way and not the other way?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have a NULL value for in the cabletypes table.  Try this version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cable_no FROM bundle_lanes 
        WHERE cable_no NOT IN (SELECT cable_no FROM cabletypes where cable_no is not null)
        ORDER BY cable_no ASC
```

Comment: that works too, thanks for all the different options, which is best to use for performance and effectiveness?

Comment: ok so I have another thing to add now... I have a section number that also accompanies a cable number, so I've been trying to implement what you guys gave by doing: SELECT DISTINCT cable_no FROM bundle_lanes 
        WHERE cable_no AND section_no NOT IN (SELECT cable_no AND section_no FROM cabletypes WHERE cable_no IS NOT null)
        ORDER BY cable_no ASC        which works, but then it still shows the unwanted cable number even if both cable AND section numbers are in both tables... but then if a section number is not there, it works correctly, just want there to be NO option if both exist.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out using this: SELECT DISTINCT bundle_lanes.cable_no 
  FROM bundle_lanes LEFT OUTER JOIN cabletypes 
  ON bundle_lanes.cable_no = cabletypes.cable_no AND bundle_lanes.section_no = cabletypes.section_no
  WHERE cabletypes.cable_no IS NULL
  ORDER BY bundle_lanes.cable_no